# Give permission to list and a few items

Tags: 2013, list, permissions, item

I have a SharePoint 2013 list which contains many items (about 50).

But I can't find a way to give some users access to the list and only a few items appart from adding the read permissions for all items, then removing the read permission for these users in each item they're not related.

For example, let's take this list of customers with their name, language and country.

> **Customers**
>
> John - EN - UK
>
> Jack - EN - US
>
> Jean - FR - CA

Is there a way to give access to the customers which language is "EN" and to the list itself without adding the read permissions for the user on the list and having to delete the read permission on the FR item?

It would have been so easy if we could set permissions on views, but unfortunately, it seems we can't.

The only solution I could find until now is to create another list which would contains links to the items.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried item-level permission?

Comment: @Aveenav Are you talking about setting permissions on the item itself? If so, that's the problem since I also need to give access to the list. Otherwise, the users will have to go through links to access the items instead of the list.

Comment: Can you consider making folders for each language or Country and breaking inheritance of the folder? For eg: Only UK customers will have access to UK folder, they will not see US and FR folders

Comment: @Unnie In fact, the only concern I have with this is that we are supposed to use folder in a last resort, no? Still, you can add your comment as an answer since it's a solution which is easy to manage afterward, and if there's no other solution by tomorrow, I'll accept it as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: folders seem a good workaround for this to achieve, and maybe you can create a view and edit it in sharepoint designer, using custom JavaScript you can query and populate it/hide or show field, etc.

Comment: Folders are a good option for breaking inheritance. Best practice is to define unique scopes at the highest level possible, and to manage them with groups rather than individual users: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg128955.aspx

Comment: You can use folders, or break down to separate lists. Folders are not actually the last resort, in some cases they are quite useful(like handling thresholds in large lists). They're mostly fine unless users don't keep nesting them and start using document libraries like shared drives. http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2008/12/23/security-trimming-a-list-view-aspx/

Comment: @Unnie Please add your comment as the answer so I can accept it since it looks like it's the easiest way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create folders for each Country/Language and break inheritance and keep unique permission at folder level.This will help you to keep all records in single list and also will avoid List Item level permissions.